# Converting miRNA names

Tags: cell-biology, microrna

I need to convert all of my microRNA names e.g. hsa-miR-30e-5p to e.g. entrez gene IDs, ensemble IDs or another ID. Does anyone know a good ID conversion tool for microRNAs?

(I managed to convert it to miRBase ID e.g. MIMAT0000692, but [David](https://david.ncifcrf.gov/home.jsp) does not recognise them apparently)

Comment: Does this help? https://www.biostars.org/p/85571/

Comment: miRbase is kind of an official database for miRNAs. So it is better to have miRbase ids for miRNAs rather than other (ensembl, entrez etc) ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there're no ids for a mature sequence. You better search for a parent sequence ids. You could check, but it also seems that HGNC ids are -miR-30E- part.
So you could try [Ensemble search](http://useast.ensembl.org/biomart/martview/46480e5ddc2da4001055568fd020e767) (you should input names in 'Filter'-'GENE' section) or use [Genenames](http://rest.genenames.org/fetch/symbol/MIR30E). As you see, it has API, and you could use it programmatically with HGNC ids.